# How can i change the route parameter's name

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes, global-asax

I'm implementing some `api`. That api sends to me `http get requests`. All names of parameters are in uppercase.

So, query string looks like this:

```
myURL?CALLID=1&STATE=START
```

I've added new MapRoute to my `Global.asax`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "VotBox",
    "VotBox/Notify/{CALLID}{STATE}",
    new { controller = "VotBox", action = "Notify", CALLID = -1, STATE = ""},
    new { STATE = "STARTCALL" }
);
```

And my `Controller` has parameters with names in uppercase. So my `Action` look like this:

```
public class VotBoxController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public void Notify(int CALLID, string STATE)
    {

    }
}
```

But i want that my parameters were named in standard CamelCase.
How i can change parameter names so action looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public void Notify(int callId, string state)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your specific route definition, it will work with all the below urls

```
/VotBox/Notify/4/STARTCALL
/VotBox/Notify/4/startcall
/VotBox/Notify?CALLID=3&STATE=anyString
/VotBox/Notify?callId=3&state=anyString
```

Casing of the param name does not matter. It will work for both lowercase or upper case.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your `routes.MapRoute` to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "VotBox",
    "VotBox/Notify/{callId}{state}",
    new { controller = "VotBox", action = "Notify", callId = -1, state= ""},
    new { state= "STARTCALL" }
);
```